# Broken Links (Badges) in Stack Exchange Tour

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, broken-link, tour

Clicking on the badges (Student, Editor, Good Answer, Civic Duty, Famous Question) in the [Stack Exchange Tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) leads to a 404 page:

[image]

Comment: Indeed. It needs `meta.` in front of the URL.

Comment: @Patrick turns out it's not. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the links altogether.

Since stackexchange.com itself doesn't have badges, there are no badges to link to (the design/html was copied from the Q&A tour - and I guess this was an oversight).

The badges are there to illustrate how the sites work - on Q&A sites, the tour should (and does) link to the correct badge pages.

Comment: Well, MSE is the meta site of stackexchange.com in a sense, and does have badges, so it would make some sense to link here in my  opinion.

Comment: MSE has its own tour page - the badges there link correctly. Frankly, if someone is looking at se.com, I don't want them to (accidentally) go to a different site, which is why I removed the links.