# Broken links for tags on the Stack Exchange Tour page

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, 404-not-found, unicorns, tour

Tags [unicorns](/questions/tagged/unicorns) and [daisies](/questions/tagged/daisies) refer to the 404 page from the [Tour page](https://stackexchange.com/tour) of stackexchange.com:

> [image: no unicorns]

I see a panda instead of unicorns! Is it because unicorns do not exist?

> [image: panda instead]

Looks like somebody forgot to fix them when he has made a fix [for the badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279782/339911).

Comment: The more I think about it, se.com should not have this tour to begin with. The tour fits Q&A sites, which se.com is not.